# How to use flash animation in Panda.js?

Tags: html, flash

on Panda.js HTML5 framework it says that it support Adobe flash animations, how can I do that, I researched a lot online but couldnt find any way.

If it means exporting animation to spritesheet, then it is no different from others and certainly not a special feature to be mentioned. Is there any way to use animations directly?

without the flash player ofcourse

Answer (score 1):

Panda.js does not support Flash animations, you can only use the exported spritesheets, well, like the others.